# Why and how is hole trapping happens by acceptor impurities only and not by donor impurities of a semiconductor detector?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why and how is hole trapping happens by acceptor impurities only and not by donor impurities of a semiconductor detector?
Am I missing very basic phenomena?

Comment: It's all matter of energy; definitely a hole could be temporarily localized even at an ionized donor site, leading to double positive charging of it. But the energy would typically be few eV above Fermi level → extremely unlikely at room temperature equilibrium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donor impurities donate electrons, leaving behind a positively charged ion. They thus can trap negatively charged electrons.

On the other hand, accepter impurities take an electron, becoming negatively charged ions. Thus, they repel electrons, but may trap positively charged holes.

Trapping in this context means that an electron/hole is essentially occupying one of the outer atomic orbitals of the donor/acceptor (rather than falling into an inner orbital, from which electron was donater/accepted), where these orbitals are significantly hybridized with the band. Thus it makes more sense to describe it as a band electron bound on a positively/negatively charged impurity.

Comment: Sir, nice answer. Can you please share some references for me to understand it better.

Comment: I am glad that it helps. You could start with wikipedia articles on doping, acceptors, and donors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor#Doping For more in-depth discussions you could look up the books by Ashkroft&Mermin or Kittel: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Solid-Physics-Charles-Kittel/dp/047141526X , https://www.amazon.com/Solid-State-Physics-Neil-Ashcroft/dp/8131500527/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=ashcroft+mermin&qid=1622792513&s=books&sr=1-1